# How can I allow only letters in React.js input form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

there is a form I created using react-hook-form. I want to check the character for the name input in this form.

I created Regex in pattern section, my control works,

[image]

but I want to **prevent entering numbers and symbols**. Just letter only (including Turkish characters)

[image]

How can I do that? Does the input mask library work? I would be glad if you help.

codes and output are available below. Thanks.

```
<FormInput
  capitalize={{ textTransform: 'capitalize' }}
  // control={control}
  style="full"
  id="name"
  type="text"
  name="name"
  gtagStart={gtagStart}
  label="Name*"
  onChangeFunc={keyEvent => {
    const { value } = keyEvent.target;
    const lowerCaseAll = value.toLowerCase();
    keyEvent.target.value = lowerCaseAll.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lowerCaseAll.slice(1);
  }}
  register={register({
    required: {
      message: 'Required',
      value: true,
    },
    pattern: {
      message: 'Please enter valid name',
      value: /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+)*$/,
    },
  })}
  error={errors.name}
/>
```

EDIT: I found a solution! Thanks for everyone who helped to me for this question.

Solution: With regex, I specified the characters to be entered in the input, then I defined them in onChangeFunc. The function has both character control and capitalizes text.

```
onChangeFunc={keyEvent => {
                  const { value } = keyEvent.target;
                  const lowerCaseAll = value.toLowerCase();
                  const replaceAll = lowerCaseAll.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lowerCaseAll.slice(1);
                  keyEvent.target.value = replaceAll.replace(/[^a-zA-ZşŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ\- ]/g, '');
                }}
```

Comment: chek this package it may help https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-text-mask

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Do you need to support latin and turkish letters only or letters as a whole?

Comment: @zhulien only latin and turkish letters. joseph i'll check this package

Answer (score 0):

add pattern like this:

```
 pattern: {
    value: /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/,
    message: "Please Enter a valid name",
 },
```

Answer (score -1):

You ca use the following Regex
Only valid for letters and spaces

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

Check it out and let me know..